# What impact does a red logo have?

Tags: user-behavior

I'm not sure if this question is right for UX, but I'm not sure where to place it otherwise so I'll do it here. If it doesn't belong here, please move it.

I'm busy working on a new project, and of course: it needs a website and a logo. I was thinking about a red logo. It's beautiful, but I'm not sure if the color red will have a positive impact on the 'experience' of the user.

For example, when I get one of those annoying popups and they have a green button saying 'Close' and a red one saying 'Proceed', I will click the red one automatically. I'm afraid such a thing will happen with a red logo.

This may look like a weird question to you but I'm really not sure. Will a red logo have a negative impact on the 'experience' of the user, and will it have an impact on the time the user will stay on the website? And of course, does it decrease the chance that the user buys a product?

Comment: There are plenty of red logos in the corporate world.

Comment: @BartGijssens Bedankt.

Comment: @BartGijssens Please don't put answers in a comment: [http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would link you to a few pages about Color Psychology. The color should somehow reflect the brand or feelings that brand evokes. Red color is always very intense and it evokes strong emotions (coca cola and its happy american dream with all those families and childrens), love and rebels (Rolling Stones logo). It also evokes strength (for example Red Bull) and can summon appetite (McDonald's boxes).

[Link1](http://d.pr/i/smpH) or [Link2](http://lh6.ggpht.com/-6HohDltSi1Q/UxnAH5HZhbI/AAAAAAAAFww/lglYw3Xm2V8/Role-Of-Color-Psychology-in-the-Designing-of-Professional-Logos-1_thumb%25255B2%25255D.png?imgmax=800) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_psychology)

And to your questions: The color of logo shouldn't have impact on the 'experience' or time they spend on your website... Green color can decrease the chance as well when it is used inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks, those links are very interesting! Would you mind giving me the links?

Comment: They are in the middle of my answer: link1, link2 and wiki.

Comment: Yes, I know, but those (1nd and 2nd) are screenshots, right? I would like the links to the real page :)

Comment: http://m.fastcompany.com/3028378/leadership-now/what-your-logos-color-says-about-your-company-infographic and http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/2516608/ . Hope it helped. :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think a red logo has a negative impact considering the many iconic red logos. Levi's, Coca Cola, Leica, Red Cross, Lego, Canon, Virgin, Mitsubishi...

Red is the color of blood, and because of this it has historically been associated with sacrifice, danger and courage. Modern surveys in the United States and Europe show red is the color most commonly associated with heat, fire, beauty, activity, passion, sexuality, anger, love, and joy. In China and many other Asian cultures, it is the color of happiness. Red was the first color to get a name. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red).

Of course the logo should suit the image of the company and its brand identity. I would not use a red logo for an undertaker or a wellness spa for example.